# Hide and Show KML Layers

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I have a KML File to import on google maps and then I want to show and hide some layers, I have a tag (visibility) that controls the visibility of the layers. How can I change that tag to reproduce what I want?

I think the project doesn't have anything to show and hide a specific layer

The file is here https://app.box.com/s/jrfqhcgg0gz303fu0s1w8k3ppi8srh96

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

Comment: show you code  and not your link .... to a zip files .....

Comment: its not the code.. its the KML file

Comment: then shouw your actula code   ..

Comment: edited, its just the google example